# How to control folder structure when exporting a Runnable JAR in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Desired result: A folder named 'examples' in the root of my 'Runnable' JAR.

In Eclipse, when clicking 'Export' > 'Runnable JAR file', there is no option to choose which resources to export into the new JAR. After I execute the operation to create a 'Runnable JAR file', my 'examples' folders sitting in my project root does not appear in the resultant JAR. Is there a way to use Eclipse's 'Export' > 'Runnable Jar' facility, while still having control over the folder structure of the final result? (I'm using Eclipse 3.7/Indigo)

Comment: I found a "solution" for my case... since the resources where "kinda" source related, i put them into the source folder (in this way, they are exported to the root, but inside the folder of the resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export runnable jar file using eclipse, it only export the compiled classes and the libraries. You can of cause go to `project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Class Folder`. Add the *examples* folder to the build path and then re-run the export procedure again. The ideal way would probably use the generated build.xml and modify the target to generated the jar file.

Comment: When I add my folders using this method, the runnable jar loses the "examples" folder name. So, all the contents of the "examples" folder are dumped in the root folder. Any suggestions on why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I also get the same problem as TheBlueNotebook

Comment: This solutions does not work... I need to automate the export so that specific project folders get exported AS IS, not dumped on the ROOT of the JAR! :\